# DataGridView click event doesn't always fire

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, clicklistener

I have a `DataGridView`. Its `Cell_Content_Click` is not firing each time I select a cell. It does fires but not at each click.

I want to get content of selected cell in my string variable 'selected'. Here is what I am doing:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value != null)
    {
        selected = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `CellContentClick` event only fires when the content (text) inside a cell is clicked.

Use the [`CellClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick(v=vs.110).aspx) event instead of [`CellContentClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick(v=vs.110).aspx), since that event fires when *any* part of the cell is clicked (not just the content inside it).