# GridView_CellContentClick responds randomly

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a fairly simply form with a gridview control on it (C#).  It would be really cool if the control raised an event when clicked on as advertised by the CellContentClick event.  And it does.  But with random success.  Sometimes it fires the event, sometimes not.

The most useful suggestion was to use the CellClick event [(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26690742/datagridview-click-event-doesnt-always-fire)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26690742/datagridview-click-event-doesnt-always-fire) but this does not seem to fire anything at all.  My code at this stage for the event is not really worth publsiihing as I am only listning for the event but here it is anyway:

```
        private void plantSystemsGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int row = e.RowIndex;
    }
```

or alternatively:

```
        private void plantSystemsGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int row = e.RowIndex;
    }
```

Please suggest how I should be using the gridview control.

P.

EDIT:  in case this is relevant.  It is bound to a `List<someObject>` as Datasource.

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name!  - Usually the reason is that one doesn't actually hit the __content__.. Cellclick is indeed recommended. Please post relevant code! Atm we don' see any work that could be done in the click event.. did you set a breakpoint? Does it never or only sometimes halt?

Comment: So the `CellContentClick` only fires when the actual content is clicked (as opposed to a cell with some content in it, ie non empty).  The behaviour I am looking for is for an event to fire when any cell is clicked anywhere (empty or non empty).  Assuming this is `CellClick` but this never fires.  @TaW, yes I added breakpoints and I have renamed my controls.  Tx. P.

Comment: And so this is now solved.  There seemed to have crept a discrepancy in with the form.Designer.cs definition for the `plantSystemsDataGridView_CellClick` and the source file resulting in CellClick never acting correctly.  All fine now. Tx. P.